# Recursive Php function not working

Tags: php, function, recursion, jstree

I am trying to display in a table all the child nodes from an ID passed as a parameter. I used a recursive function in PHP to do that. 
The only problem is that it displays only the 1st child and not all of them.

[This is the Tree.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U33as.jpg)

The PHP Function:

```
$data = array();
$index = array();
$albero = array();
$query = $conn->query("SELECT id, insertedby FROM utenti where insertedby is not null ORDER BY id");
$query->data_seek(0);
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $id        = $row["id"];
    $parent_id = $row["insertedby"] === NULL ? "NULL" : $row["insertedby"];
    $data[$id] = $row;
    $index[$parent_id][] = $id;
}

function findNodeLevel($parent_id, $level, $idtosearch)
{
    global $data, $index;
    $parent_id = $parent_id === NULL ? "NULL" : $parent_id; 
    print_r($data);
    if (isset($index[$parent_id])) {
        foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
            $current_id = $data[$id]["id"];
            if($current_id == $idtosearch) {
                $levell = $level + 1;
                return $levell;
            }
            findNodeLevel($_SESSION['id'], $level + 1, $idtosearch);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

[Result of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caP1b.jpg)

The array data displayed in the 2nd image is the $data array.

The while loop:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id, email, tipoutente, fullname, datainserimento FROM utenti WHERE inseritoda = " . $_SESSION['id']);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr class=\"righe\">";

                if($row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO PRIVATO" || $row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO NEGOZI" || $row['tipoutente'] == "GRUPPO ASSOCIAZIONI") {
                    $livello = findNodeLevel($_SESSION['id'], 0, $row['id']);
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">$progressivoutenti</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['tipoutente'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['datainserimento'] . "</td>";
                    //echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $row['datadiff'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"gruppi\">" . $livello . "</td>";
                } else {
                    $livello = findNodeLevel($_SESSION['id'], 0, $row['id']);
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">$progressivoutenti</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['fullname'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['tipoutente'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['datainserimento'] . "</td>";
                    //echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $row['datadiff'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td class=\"dati\">" . $livello . "</td>";
                }

                $progressivoutenti++;
            echo "</tr>";   

        }
    echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Where are you calling findNodeLevel?

Comment: I call it in a while loop where I get the nodes from a database that are the same as the nodes in the jstree. I call it like: $level = findNodeLevel($_SESSION['id'], 0, $row['id']);

Comment: This while? "while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {" I dont see it there...

Comment: Added it now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the recursive function, when you call it again, aren't you passing the wrong parameter for parent_id ?

```
function findNodeLevel($parent_id, $level, $idtosearch)
{
    global $data, $index;
    $parent_id = $parent_id === NULL ? "NULL" : $parent_id; 
    print_r($data);
    if (isset($index[$parent_id])) {
        foreach ($index[$parent_id] as $id) {
            $current_id = $data[$id]["id"];
            if($current_id == $idtosearch) {
                $levell = $level + 1;
                return $levell;
            }
            findNodeLevel($current_id, $level + 1, $idtosearch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I did a bad mistake sorry, now it displays the table with all the child nodes, but the level is 1 for everyone.

Comment: Strange, are you certain the code is passing $level +1 on the inner call?